# Arrangement in a row

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many ways can $8$ people be seated in a row if

(a) There are $4$ men and $4$ women and no $2$ men or $2$ women can sit next to each other?

(b) There are $5$ men and they must sit next to each other?

---

I got $4!\cdot{5\choose 4}\cdot4!$ for first one and $5!\cdot4!$ for second one.

I am a bit sceptical about it .

Comment: There should be only one question per post.  Some justification of what you got would help us explain what is right or wrong.

Comment: In the first case, it is evident that men and women must sit alternatively. Thus there are a total of two arrangements. Now the $4$ men and women can be permuted in $4!$ ways. Thus the answer in first case is $2\times (4!)^2$. In the second case, we first have to choose seats for those five men, ie $\binom{4}{1}$ ways, then the men can be permuted in $5!$ ways and women can be permuted in $3!$ ways. Therefore the answer in second case is $5!4!$.

Comment: @RossMillikan I have spoken about till where I have reached with the solution and coming to 'one question per post',  pardon me , I am new to this site, I am bound to make mistakes, but will learn how to post well XD.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  You should explain your reasoning rather than just stating an answer since that makes it easier for readers of your question to detect any errors you may have made.

Answer (score 2):

> $(a)$ Consider the first chair. We can put there a man or a woman.
>
> Suppose we put one of the $4$ men. Then for the second chair, we must put one of the $4$ women. For the third chair, we will have to put one of the $3$ remaining men. And so on, until we fill the row.
>
> By the product rule, there are $4^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 2^2 \cdot 1^2 = 576$ distinct ways of doing this.
>
> The same argument applies if we put a woman in the first chair.
>
> So the total ways of sit these $8$ people in this condition is $2 \cdot 576 = 1152$.

---

> $(b)$ We have $8$ chairs and we want to put $5$ men together. So in terms of their position, we can put such a group in $4$ distinct ways (starting in first chair until the fifth chair, starting in the second chair until the sixth chair, and so on).
>
> These men are able to switch places between them, so the group of $5$ men can sit in their $5$ chairs in $5!=120$ distinct ways.
>
> Next, we have to put the remaining $3$ people in $3$ chairs and they can switch places between them, so there are $3! = 6$ distinct ways of placing them.
>
> By the product rule, we conclude that are $4 \cdot 5! \cdot 3! = 4 \cdot 120 \cdot 6 = 2880$ distinct sequences in this condition.

---

In your answer, part $(a)$ is wrong and part $(b)$ is right.

Comment: $4^2\cdot 3^2 \cdot 2^2 \cdot 1^2 \neq 30$

Comment: @MatthewHolder you’re right, it was a typo, it is already fixed. Thank you for the feedback